# Routing requests to containers based on path?

Tags: traefik

When a request comes through to my domain I want all `/snap` requests to be forwarded to my `thumbor` container along with the path. I can't seem to get this working I've tried many different modifiers.

So for example any request to `https://addmysnap.local/snap/image/3234234234/profile.jpg` gets routed to the `thumbor` container as `/image/some-other-stuff/3234234234/profile.jpg`.

The `some-other-stuff` part will be string that allows me to watermark the image.

Here's what I've got so far ...

```
  thumbor:
    image: minimalcompact/thumbor:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
      - default
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - - "traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:addmysnap.local,ReplacePathRegex: ^/snap/(.*) /$${1}"
      - "traefik.basic.port=80"
    environment:
      UPLOAD_ENABLED: 1
```

This doesn't work though and I the following error:

```
thumbor_1   | 2018-09-29 18:16:44 thumbor:WARNING Malformed URL: /snap/image/051a30f09fe340cbac13e9d58d09bee4/image.jpg
```

Not sure why it's malformed, or why `/snap` is being passed through.

Any ideas how to do this?